# Javascript: How to reconstruct a nested object into another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following nested object:

```
var test = {'a': {'name': 'CO2', 'x': ['US', 'UK', 'China'], 'y': [1,2,3]}, 
            'b': {'name': 'GHG', 'x': ['US', 'UK', 'China'], 'y': [4,5,6]}
           };
```

I have to dynamically iterate and get the ideal result:

```
[{'country': 'US', 'CO2': 1, 'GHG': 4},
{'country': 'UK', 'CO2': 2, 'GHG': 5},
{'country': 'China', 'CO2': 3, 'GHG': 6}]
```

I have already asked but it was the thing with arrays and I can't get how to work with objects.

I can iterate and get an array of 2 objects but it is not what I needed

```
var traces = [];

Object.keys(test).forEach(function(key) { 
  var keys = test[key].x;
  var values = test[key].y;
  var name = test[key].name;


  var trace = keys.map((country, index) => ({
     country,
     [name]: values[index]

  }));

traces.push(trace);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) of the `test` object. Add each country as a key to the accumulator object and the object needed in the output as its value. Loop through each country in `x` and update the accumulator.

```js
const test={a:{name:"CO2",x:["US","UK","China"],y:[1,2,3]},b:{name:"GHG",x:["US","UK","China"],y:[4,5,6]}},

    values = Object.values(test),
  
    group = values.reduce((acc, { name, x, y }) => {
      x.forEach((country, i) => {
        acc[country] ||= { country }
        acc[country][name] = y[i]
      })
      return acc
    }, {}),
    
    output = Object.values(group)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: great solution @adiga .... please could you explain this line `acc[country] ||= { country }`  i'm learning from answers :)

Comment: @Codenewbie It's using the [Logical OR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) and [Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). It's equivalent to `acc[country] = acc[country] || { "country": country }`. The goal is to create an accumulator object is like `{ US: { country: "US", 'CO2': 1 } }`. If the accumulator object doesn't have `US` as key, add the key and set it to `{ country: 'US' }`

Comment: @adiga Wow they are amazing and very handy, tysm for explaining gbu :) ...  :)

Comment: @Codenewbie there are two more similar conditional assignment operators AND `&&=` and Nullish assignment [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). So, `let a = null; a ??= 'value'` will assign a new value to `a` only if `a` is null or undefined.

Comment: @adiga just saw all of them bro :)  thanks for mentioning .... so kind of you